# What's the difference between CSS3 translate method and CSS2 relative positioning?

Tags: css, css-transforms

It seems that both of them could make the element move from its current position. Are these two methods interchangeable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two methods are not exactly the same thing: Translating an element will not require to change its `top`, `left`, `right` or `bottom` CSS properties, so in the same way `offsetTop/offseLeft` Javascript properties are not affected by a CSS translation. Beside, the position of the element could be also `static` (and thus no `z-index` is required)

If you use `position: relative` instead, you will change those properties to visually achieve the same effect.

Example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LkLey/

Of course if you have to deal with old browser (like `IE8` or `FF2`) the necessary choice is relative positioning, otherwise I can't see a clear convenience on choosing one of the two methods (well, to be honest relative positioning has no need of multipe prefixes `-moz-`, `-webkit-` ... to work everywhere) so the choice is up to you (and it depends on the layout).

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little bit confused. How come the top, left, right or bottom CSS properties don't chage? I mean all of these properties set the corresponding edge of an element to a unit to the left/right/up/down to its normal position.So if you use translate method to move an element away from its normal position, they should change according to my understanding.

Comment: @chaonextdoor: Transforms work rather differently from your regular relative positioning. If you had a 3D transform, for example, how should an element's offsets be computed?

Comment: It looks like `translate()` will in fact alter an element's `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` properties now. I wonder when that changed...

Comment: What? In which browser have you seen this?