# In css what is the purpose of transformY?

Tags: css

I have been looking at some CSS and found out that it was using `top` as well as `transformY`. I want to know why both are being used in this specific scenario.

Following is the CSS attached to image element

```
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top: 50%;
left: 0;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%)
```

I would like to know that what exactly is the purpose of using **transform** here ?

Comment: to align the element vertically at the center, `-50%` of the `translateY`  is based on the element height, while the top percentage is based on the relative parent height.

Comment: It looks like it's shifting it up by 50% of the element's height - try toggling the transform on and off [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2rq83usx/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the CSS transform:translate() property ultimately for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110972/what-is-the-css-transformtranslate-property-ultimately-for) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184458/transform-translate-50-50

Comment: @MohsinSethi if you want to ask questions specific to a case scenario, you could also post the relevant HTML code too i.e. a complete MRE see (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then I would understand how it's not a duplicate but asking just "what is the purpose of transform()" is a duplicate in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `absolute` position on an element, you can use `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` CSS attributes to position it in relation to the nearest parent which has a defined position (e.g. `relative`).

`translate`, whether its `translateX`, `translateY` or just `translate`, moves your element from its calculated position in relations to itself. A good example for its usage would be if you wanted to center an absolute positioned element inside its parent.

Lets see an example:

```css
#parent {
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: blue;
}

#parent #child {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
}

#parent2 {
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: green;
}

#parent2 #child2 {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <label id="child">LABEL</label>
</div>

<div id="parent2">
  <label id="child2">LABEL2</label>
</div>
```

As you can see, on `child2` I use `translate` in order to really center it, since `top` and `left` places its upper left corner on the center of `parent`. By using `translate(-50%, -50%)`, I'm moving it half of its height up and left, in order to position it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you use `top: 50%` the border at the top will be exact at 50%.

Now you use `translateY(-50%)` to move the element 50% of its height up.

At this example you can see that with only `top: 50%` the top border is at 50%. But you want the element itself to be centered vertically so you would need to add tranlate like in the second exapmle

```css
div {
   background: red;
   height: 300px;
   width: 300px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

With translate

```css
div {
   background: red;
   height: 300px;
   width: 300px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Often you will see properties like:

```
top: 50%,
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

You can use it for X aswell. This is often used for `absolute` and `fixed` divs to center it vertically and horizontally