# How can I do this CSS transform with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, transition

I was using transit.js before, which works beautifully, but to reduce script dependancies I want to do it myself. I have searched EVERYWHERE but to no avail.

Before:

```
main.stop().transition({
x: -thex
}, 600)
```

Now (which doesn't work):

```
main.animate({ borderSpacing: -thex }, {
    step: function(now,fx) {
        main.css('transform',"translateX("+now + "px) translateZ(0)");
    },
    duration:600
});
```

What doesn't work about it is that it snaps to the correct position with no animation, and for some reason animates out (in the other direction) by about 10px.

Any ideas?

Of if you know of another way to do CSS transform with jQuery/CSS/LESS with a dynamic value, do let me know!

Comment: Is translation necessary ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007093/whats-the-difference-between-css3-translate-method-and-css2-relative-positionin

Comment: CSS transitions can animate CSS transforms, so if you are using a CSS transition you won't need to define a step function since you won't need to use jQuery animations.

Comment: Yes, because it's for a large mobile site. Performance is very important to me.

Comment: Doug could you elaborate? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Could you add a fiddle so that we can see exactly what you're doing and the HTML/CSS that this JS is affecting?

Comment: @MattDiamant the dynamic value is based on many other factors, so I'm not able to pick this out of the code (at least easily!)

Comment: If it helps, here's a link http://airwalk-design.com/?via=logo - click on the hamburger lines to see the menu come out :)

Comment: You can hard code the dynamic value for now. We just want to see the animation failing.

Comment: I can't seem to get this working either http://jsfiddle.net/QHFn6/